# Create an error message if certain cells are empty

Tags: google-sheets

I've been messing around with a spreadsheet for a while now and got it mostly working besides one part.

I have two columns, if a cell in the first column is "1", but the cell in the same row but different column is "empty" I want to output an error message.

I can do that for a single set of cells very easily with an IF, like so

```
=IF(J35 = 1,IF(ISBLANK(K35) = TRUE,"error","ok"),"ok")
```

But I have around 165 rows that I'd need to check that for.

Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

[image]

(The 1's and 0's are tickboxes in my actual table, ticked = 1, unticked = 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the `ARRAYFORMULA` is what you need.
Please try the following formula instead
*(Note adjust the ranges `J3:J11` and `K3:K11` to your needs and since you have tick-boxes change `1` to `TRUE`)*

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(J3:J11 = TRUE,IF(ISBLANK(K3:K11) = TRUE,"error","ok"),"ok"))
```

Please read more about [`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.
I actually tried to use the ARRAYFORMULA before, forgot to mention that. But my problem with that is, that it doesn't return one cell with the text "error", but it returns either "ok" or "error" for each cell.
That's how it's supposed to work obviously.

I've been messing around with it for a little bit now, but I can't seem to figure out a way to check that array for "error" and then only return it once.

Comment: Alright, after a lot of googling later, I now got this:
     
     =IF(ISERROR(MATCH("problem",ARRAYFORMULA(IF(J33:J38 = 1,IF(ISBLANK(K33:K38) = TRUE,"problem","ok"),"ok")),0)),"","ERROR")


Which does exactly what I needed, thanks :)

Comment: Glad it worked out for you and were able to modify it to your needs. Please feel free to update my answer including your modification.